# Fixed-effect model matrix is rank deficient

Tags: r, lmer

I get the following error when I try to run a mixed effects model:

```
> LMER_MIXED <- as.data.frame(LMER_MIXED)
> m2 <- lmer(log_bid_price ~ . - state + (1|state), data = LMER_MIXED)
fixed-effect model matrix is rank deficient so dropping 1 column / coefficient
```

This is **after** using findLinearCombos from the caret package to see if there are any linearly combinable columns:

```
> LMER_MIXED <- cbind(cbind(LMER_DESIGN, state), log_bid_price)
> findLinearCombos(LMER_MIXED)
$linearCombos
list()

$remove
NULL
```

Any thoughts on how to remove this warning and find a column that is not linearly separable?

```
    > str(LMER_MIXED)
'data.frame':   11697 obs. of  63 variables:
 $ (Intercept)                                : num  1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ month10                                    : num  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ month11                                    : num  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ month12                                    : num  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ month2                                     : num  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ month3                                     : num  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ month4                                     : num  1 1 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 ...
 $ month5                                     : num  0 0 1 1 1 1 0 1 0 0 ...
 $ month6                                     : num  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 ...
 $ month7                                     : num  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ month8                                     : num  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ month9                                     : num  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ weekend1                                   : num  0 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ weekendNone                                : num  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ day_of_week1                               : num  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 ...
...
```

I guess the issue is that the Intercept column is a linear combination?

Comment: I would have thought it should be possible to discover the answer by examining `str(LMER_MIXED)`and the output of `print(m2)`  ... neither of which has been offered.

Comment: Thanks @BondedDust. I updated to provide the top of the output. Maybe is the issue is that the intercept is not linearly separable?

Comment: It might be. I think you might have created your own dummy variables. I suspect it you `month` variables that are causing the problem. That's not usually good practice in R regression situations.

Comment: Reproducible example?