# lme4::lmer reports "fixed-effect model matrix is rank deficient", do I need a fix and how to?

Tags: r, regression, linear-regression, lme4, mixed-models

I am trying to run a mixed-effects model that predicts `F2_difference` with the rest of the columns as predictors, but I get an error message that says

> fixed-effect model matrix is rank deficient so dropping 7 columns / coefficients.

From this link, [Fixed-effects model is rank deficient](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29241492/fixed-effect-model-matrix-is-rank-deficient), I think I should use `findLinearCombos` in the R package `caret`. However, when I try `findLinearCombos(data.df)`, it gives me the error message

> Error in qr.default(object) : NA/NaN/Inf in foreign function call (arg 1) 
>       In addition: Warning message: 
>       In qr.default(object) : NAs introduced by coercion

My data does not have any NAs - What could be causing this? (Sorry if the answer is various obvious - I am new to R).

All of my data are factors except the numerical value that I am trying to predict. Here is a small sample of my data.

```
sex <- c("f", "m", "f", "m")
nasal <- c("TRUE", "TRUE", "FALSE", "FALSE")
vowelLabel <- c("a", "e", "i", "o")
speaker <- c("Jim", "John", "Ben", "Sally")
word_1 <- c("going", "back", "bag", "back")
type <- c("coronal", "coronal", "labial", "velar")
F2_difference <- c(345.6, -765.8, 800, 900.5)
data.df <- data.frame(sex, nasal, vowelLabel, speaker,
                      word_1, type, F2_difference
                      stringsAsFactors = TRUE)
```

Edit:
Here is some more code, if it helps.

```
formula <- F2_difference ~ sex + nasal + type + vowelLabel + 
           type * vowelLabel + nasal * type +
           (1|speaker) + (1|word_1)

lmer(formula, REML = FALSE, data = data.df)
```

**Editor edit:**

The OP did not provide sufficient number of test data to allow an actual run of the model in `lmer` for the reader. But this is not too big a issue. This is still a very good post!

Answer (score 62, accepted):

You are slightly over-concerned with the warning message:

> fixed-effect model matrix is rank deficient so dropping 7 columns / coefficients.

It is a warning not an error. There is neither misuse of `lmer` nor ill-specification of model formula, thus you will obtain an estimated model. But to answer your question, I shall strive to explain it.

---

During execution of `lmer`, your model formula is broken into a **fixed effect formula** and a **random effect formula**, and for each a **model matrix** is constructed. Construction for the fixed one is via the standard model matrix constructor `model.matrix`; construction for the random one is complicated but not related to your question, so I just skip it.

For your model, you can check what the fixed effect model matrix looks like by:

```
fix.formula <- F2_difference ~ sex + nasal + type + vowelLabel + 
               type * vowelLabel + nasal * type

X <- model.matrix (fix.formula, data.df)
```

All your variables are factor so `X` will be binary. Though [`model.matrix` applies `contrasts` for each factor and their interaction](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41032858/4891738), it is still possible that `X` does not end up with full column rank, as a column may be a linear combination of some others (*which can either be precise or numerically close*). In your case, [some levels of one factor may be nested in some levels of another](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41400392/4891738).

Rank deficiency can arise in many different ways. [The other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40292376/4891738) shares a CrossValidated answer offering substantial discussions, on which I will make some comments.

- For case 1, people can actually do a feature selection model via say, LASSO.
- Cases 2 and 3 are related to the data collection process. A good design of experiment is the best way to prevent rank-deficiency, but for many people who build models, the data are already there and no improvement (like getting more data) is possible. However, I would like to stress that even for a dataset without rank-deficiency, we can still get this problem if we don't use it carefully. For example, cross-validation is a good method for model comparison. To do this we need to split the complete dataset into a training one and a test one, but without care we may get a rank-deficient model from the training dataset.
- Case 4 is a big problem that could be completely out of our control. Perhaps a natural choice is to reduce model complexity, but an alternative is to try penalized regression.
- Case 5 is a numerical concern leading to numerical rank-deficiency and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42781741/4891738) is a good example.
- Cases 6 and 7 tell the fact that numerical computations are performed in finite precision. Usually these won't be an issue if case 5 is dealt with properly.

So, sometimes we can workaround the deficiency but it is not always possible to achieve this. Thus, any well-written model fitting routine, like `lm`, `glm`, `mgcv::gam`, will apply QR decomposition for `X` to only use its full-rank subspace, i.e., a maximum subset of `X`'s columns that gives a full-rank space, for estimation, [fixing coefficients associated with the rest of the columns at 0 or `NA`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44721341/4891738). The warning you got just implies this. There are originally `ncol(X)` coefficients to estimate, but due to deficiency, only `ncol(X) - 7` will be estimated, with the rest being 0 or `NA`. Such numerical workaround ensures that a least squares solution can be obtained in the most stable manner.

---

To better digest this issue, you can use `lm` to fit a linear model with `fix.formula`.

```
fix.fit <- lm(fix.formula, data.df, method = "qr", singular.ok = TRUE)
```

`method = "qr"` and `singular.ok = TRUE` are default, so actually we don't need to set it. But if we specify `singular.ok = FALSE`, `lm` will stop and complain about rank-deficiency.

```
lm(fix.formula, data.df, method = "qr", singular.ok = FALSE)
#Error in lm.fit(x, y, offset = offset, singular.ok = singular.ok, ...) : 
#  singular fit encountered
```

You can then check the returned values in `fix.fit`.

```
p <- length(coef)
coef <- fix.fit$coef
no.NA <- sum(is.na(coef))
rank <- fix.fit$rank
```

It is guaranteed that `p = ncol(X)`, but you should see `no.NA = 7` and `rank + no.NA = p`.

Exactly the same thing happens inside `lmer`. `lm` will not report deficiency while `lmer` does. This is in fact informative, as too often, I see people asking why `lm` returns `NA` for some coefficients.

---

**Update 1 (2016-05-07):**

> Let me see if I have this right: The short version is that one of my predictor variables is correlated with another, but I shouldn't worry about it. It is appropriate to use factors, correct? And I can still compare models with `anova` or by looking at the BIC?

Don't worry about the use of `summary` or `anova`. Methods are written so that the correct number of parameters (degree of freedom) will be used to produce valid summary statistics.

**Update 2 (2016-11-06):**

Let's also hear what package author of `lme4` would say: [rank deficiency warning mixed model lmer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38766155/4891738). Ben Bolker has mentioned `caret::findLinearCombos`, too, particularly because the OP there want to address deficiency issue himself.

**Update 3 (2018-07-27):**

Rank-deficiency is not a problem for valid model estimation and comparison, but could be a hazard in prediction. I recently composed a detailed answer with simulated examples on CrossValidated: [R `lm`, Could anyone give me an example of the misleading case on “prediction from a rank-deficient”?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/356083/117783) So, yes, **in theory** we should avoid rank-deficient estimation. But **in reality, there is no so-called "true model"**: we try to learn it from data. We can never compare an estimated model to "truth"; the best bet is to choose the best one from a number of models we've built. So if the "best" model ends up rank-deficient, we can be skeptical about it but probably there is nothing we can do immediately.

Answer (score 9):

This [response](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/35077/64122) does an excellent job of explaining what rank deficiency is, and what the possible causes may be.

Viz:

1. Too little data: You cannot uniquely estimate n parameters with less than n data points
2. Too many points are replicates.
3. Information in the wrong places.
4. Complicated model (too many variables)
5. Units and scaling
6. Variation in numbers: 12.001 vs. 12.005 & 44566 vs 44555
7. Data precision: Even Double-precision variables have limits