# Test whether one factor is nested in another

Tags: r

Is there an easy way to determine if one vector is *nested* within another? In other words, in the example below, each value of `bar` is associated with one and only one value of `foo`, so `bar` is nested within `foo`.

```
data.frame(foo=rep(seq(4), each=4), bar=rep(seq(8), each=2))
```

To clarify, here is the desired result:

```
foo <- rep(seq(4), each=4)
bar <- rep(seq(8), each=2)
qux <- rep(seq(8), times=2)
# using a fake operator for illustration:
bar %is_nested_in% foo  # should return TRUE
qux %is_nested_in% foo  # should return FALSE
```

Comment: Do you need `!any(duplicated(rle(bar)$values)) & all(foo %in% rle(bar)$values )`

Comment: @akrun the first part (`!any(duplicated(rle(bar)$values))`) is a stronger constraint than I want.  If `foo` were `c(1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2)` and `bar` were `c(1,2,1,2,3,4,3,4)` then `bar` would still be nested within `foo`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Suppose you have two factors `f` and `g`, and want to know whether `g` is nested in `f`.

**Method 1: For people who love linear algebra**

Consider the design matrix for two factors:

```
Xf <- model.matrix(~ f + 0)
Xg <- model.matrix(~ g + 0)
```

If `g` is nested in `f`, then the column space of `Xf` must be a subspace of the column space of `Xg`. In other word, for any linear combination of `Xf`'s columns: `y = Xf %*% bf`, equation `Xg %*% bg = y` can be solved **exactly**.

```
y <- Xf %*% rnorm(ncol(Xf))  ## some random linear combination on `Xf`'s columns
c(crossprod(round(.lm.fit(Xg, y)$residuals, 8)))  ## least squares residuals
## if this is 0, you have nesting.
```

**Method 2: For people who love statistics**

We check contingency table:

```
M <- table(f, g)
```

If all columns have only one non-zero entry, you have `g` nested in `f`. In other words:

```
all(colSums(M > 0L) == 1L)
## `TRUE` if you have nesting
```

---

Comment: For any method, you can squeeze the code into one line easily.

Comment: interesting approach, and I can see why it would work, though it seems like a bit of overkill for this specific problem.

Comment: your edited answer is much improved, and does a better job of explaining why it works. I still feel that the linear-algebra-based solution is overkill (i.e., the intermediate steps of generating a random `y` and solving a linear model), and it's easy to get the wrong answer if your data are numeric and you forget to call `factor` before generating the model matrix.  But the contingency table approach you've added is nice and succinct and works with numeric vectors.

Comment: For factors with many levels, the contingency table is large and maybe sparse. So `M <- xtabs(~ f + g, sparse = TRUE); all(Matrix::colSums(M > 0) == 1L)` should be used.

Answer (score 1):

I think this will work:

```
nested_in <- function(b, a) {
    df <- data.frame(a, b)
    all(sapply(split(df, df$b), function(i) length(unique(i$a)) < 2))
}

foo <- rep(seq(4), each=4)
bar <- rep(seq(8), each=2)
qux <- rep(seq(8), times=2)    

nested_in(bar, foo)  # TRUE
nested_in(qux, foo)  # FALSE
```