# Linear model singular because of large integer datetime in R?

Tags: r, datetime, regression, linear-regression, lm

Simple regression of random normal on date fails, but identical data with small integers instead of dates works as expected.

```
# Example dataset with 100 observations at 2 second intervals.
set.seed(1)
df <- data.frame(x=as.POSIXct("2017-03-14 09:00:00") + seq(0, 199, 2),
                 y=rnorm(100))

#> head(df)
#                     x          y
# 1 2017-03-14 09:00:00 -0.6264538
# 2 2017-03-14 09:00:02  0.1836433
# 3 2017-03-14 09:00:04 -0.8356286

# Simple regression model.
m <- lm(y ~ x, data=df)
```

The slope is missing due to singularities in the data. Calling the summary demonstrates this:

```
summary(m)

# Coefficients: (1 not defined because of singularities)
#             Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)
# (Intercept)  0.10889    0.08982   1.212    0.228
# x                 NA         NA      NA       NA
```

Could this be because of the `POSIXct` class?

```
# Convert date variable to integer.
df$x2 <- as.integer(df$x)
lm(y ~ x2, data=df)

# Coefficients:
# (Intercept)           x2  
#      0.1089           NA
```

Nope, coefficient for `x2` still missing.

What if we make the baseline of `x2` zero?

```
# Subtract minimum of x.
df$x3 <- df$x2 - min(df$x2)
lm(y ~ x3, data=df)

# Coefficients:
# (Intercept)           x3  
#   0.1312147   -0.0002255
```

This works!

One more example to rule out that this is due to datetime variable.

```
# Subtract large constant from date (data is now from 1985).
df$x4 <- df$x - 1000000000
lm(y ~ x4, data=df)

# Coefficients:
# (Intercept)           x4  
#   1.104e+05   -2.255e-04
```

Not expected (why would an identical dataset with 30 years difference cause different behaviour?), but this works too.

Could be that `.Machine$integer.max` (2147483647 on my PC) has something to do with it, but I can't figure it out. It would be greatly appreciated if someone could explain what's going on here.

Comment: Since the POSIXct origin is completely arbitrary, subtracting the minimum time is usually advisable. It also makes interpreting the coefficients a bit easier.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it could. QR factorization is stable, but is not almighty God.

```
X <- cbind(1, 1e+11 + 1:10000)
qr(X)$rank
# 1
```

Here the `X` is like the model matrix for your linear regression model, where there is a all-1 column for intercept, and there is a sequence for datetime (note the large offset).

If you center the datetime column, these two columns will be **orthogonal** hence very stable (even when solving normal equation directly!).

Comment: See also `qr(X, tol = 1e-16)$rank` or `lm.fit(cbind(1, df$x), df$y, tol = 1e-16)` for OP's example.