# How to decrease machine precision .Machine$double.eps in R?

Tags: r, epsilon

When using an R package called `did`, I get this error:

```
Error in solve.default(preV) :    system is computationally singular:
reciprocal condition number = 4.09946e-19
```

The `solve` function has an argument called `tol` whereby I can set the tolerance and thereby avoid the problem. But the package does not give this option to specify this `tol` from its top-level functions, so there is no way to set `tol` for `solve`.

I am thinking about an alternative. Since `solve()` defaults using `.Machine$double.eps` for `tol`, it would be good if I could decrease this default value. How?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That is something you can't decrease as it is sort of a C-standard. However, you can manually set `tol = 1e-20` as a function input for example, to override the default tolerance. But, this is purely a numerical workaround. You need to think about whether it is possible to address your rank-deficiency issue at your problem level. For example, rank-deficiency can arise due to the poor scaling between your data variables, and here is a simple example: [Linear model singular because of large integer datetime in R?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42781741/linear-model-singular-because-of-large-integer-datetime-in-r).

---

> I not sure as to what to do here then? As I said I'm using a function called `mp.spatt` where the `solve` function is used. So I can't really (or at least I don't know how?) add the `tol = blabla` argument in the `solve` function?

You could write a patched version of that function and rebuild the package **for your own use**. This is exactly why open-source software and packages are so GREAT.

Go to https://cran.r-project.org/package=did, download the source file `.tar.gz` for Linux, `.tgz` for Mac or `.zip` for Windows. Extract it, open the "did.R" file in the `/R` director / folder. Function `solve` is only used once in this file, so you can easily locate it:

```
W <- n*t(preatt)%*%solve(preV)%*%preatt
```

You can add `tol = 0` for simplicity. Or, you many replace `solve` by `MASS::ginv`. Actually, the package authors have been using `MASS::ginv` everywhere else in the script. It could be the case that he just forgot to replace this `solve` as well (I am checking the latest version 1.1.0 on 2018/07/11).

After fixing it, generate a `.tar.gz`, `.tgz` or `.zip` file again. Open your R, use `install.packages` to install this **specific** file, and happily use it.

Comment: But you cannot increase `tol` beyond the machine precision as that would be metaphysics so with `1e-20` you _are_ fooling yourself.

Comment: @DirkEddelbuettel what would you do in my case? how do i interpret these results? is simply because i'm trying to do something that isn't correct math?

Comment: From `help(".Machine")`, list member `double.eps`: *the smallest positive floating-point number x such that 1 + x != 1.* So no, you cannot improve on it.

Comment: when i download the did.zip from cran as suggested and open the did.r i only get the following:

#Some comments that i cant write do to character limit. 

local({
    info <- loadingNamespaceInfo()
    pkg <- info$pkgname
    ns <- .getNamespace(as.name(pkg))
    if (is.null(ns))
        stop("cannot find namespace environment for ", pkg, domain = NA);
    dbbase <- file.path(info$libname, pkg, "R", pkg)
    lazyLoad(dbbase, ns, filter = function(n) n != ".__NAMESPACE__.")
})

Comment: @ParkerWilliam Ah, I see. Windows and Mac only have pre-compiled binary rather than source code. So Open-Source is only Open on Linux. There should be a way to work around on Windows, maybe with `Rtools`. But I am not a Windows user so I don't know.

Comment: @李哲源 thanks for the help anyway, just to be sure would you agree that the error is likely to be do to a to small dataset? that the numbers become so small that R and my computer just treats them as being 0.