# Does R always return NA as a coefficient as a result of linear regression with unnecessary variables?

Tags: r, regression, linear-regression, lm, coefficients

My question is about the unnecessary predictors, namely the variables that do not provide any new linear information or the variables that are linear combinations of the other predictors. As you can see the `swiss` dataset has six variables.

```
library(swiss)
names(swiss)
# "Fertility"        "Agriculture"      "Examination"      "Education"        
# "Catholic"      "Infant.Mortality"
```

Now I introduce a new variable `ec`. It is the linear combination of `Examination` and `Education`.

```
ec <- swiss$Examination + swiss$Catholic
```

When we run a linear regression with unnecessary variables, R drops terms that are linear combinations of other terms and returns `NA` as their coefficients. The command below illustrates the point perfectly.

```
lm(Fertility ~ . + ec, swiss)

Coefficients:
 (Intercept)       Agriculture       Examination         Education            
     66.9152           -0.1721           -0.2580           -0.8709 

Catholic  Infant.Mortality    ec

  0.1041            1.0770    NA
```

However, when we regress first on `ec` and then all of the regressors as shown below,

```
lm(Fertility ~ ec + ., swiss)

 Coefficients:
 (Intercept)                ec       Agriculture       Examination           
     66.9152            0.1041           -0.1721           -0.3621           
  Education          Catholic     Infant.Mortality  
    -0.8709                NA            1.0770
```

I would expect the coefficients of both `Catholic` and `Examination` to be `NA`. The variable `ec` is linear combination of both of them but in the end the coefficient of `Examination` is not `NA` whereas that of the `Catholic` is `NA`.

Could anyone explain the reason of that?

Comment: if you have three variables `A`, `B`, `A+B` (where `A` and `B` are not themselves collinear), you can estimate parameters for any *two* of them.

Comment: This is a basic tenet of linear algebra. You have x1, x2 as a matrix, with rank 2. Now, you add a variable, x3, that is a linear combination of x1 and x2. The matrix still has rank 2.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> There will be `NA`?

Yes. Adding these columns does not enlarge column space. The resulting matrix is rank-deficient.

> How many `NA`?

It depends on the numerical rank.

```
number of NA = number of coefficients - rank of model matrix
```

In your example, after introducing `ec`, there will be one `NA`. Changing the specification order for covariates in the model formula is essentially doing column shuffling for the model matrix. This does not change the matrix rank, so you will always get only one `NA` regardless of your specification order.

> OK, but which one is `NA`?

`lm` does *LINPACK* QR factorization with **restricted** column pivoting. The order of covariates affects which one is `NA`. Generally, a *"first comes, first serves"* principle holds, and the position of `NA` is quite predictable. Take your examples for illustration. In the first specification, these co-linear terms show up in `Examination`, `Catholic`, `ec` order, so the third one `ec` has `NA` coefficient. In your second specification, these terms show up in `ec`, `Examination`, `Catholic` order, and the third one `Catholic` has `NA` coefficient. Note that coefficients estimation is not invariant to specification order, although fitted values are invariant.

If *LAPACK* QR factorization with **complete** column pivoting is taken, coefficients estimation would be invariant to specification order. However, the position of `NA` is not as predictable as in *LINPACK* case, and is purely decided numerically.

---

## Numerical Examples

LAPACK based QR factorization is implemented in `mgcv` package. Numerical rank is detected when REML estimation is used, and unidentifiable coefficients are reported as 0 (not `NA`). So we can make a comparison between `lm` and `gam` / `bam` in linear model estimation. Let's first construct a toy dataset.

```
set.seed(0)

# an initial full rank matrix
X <- matrix(runif(500 * 10), 500)
# make the last column as a random linear combination of previous 9 columns
X[, 10] <- X[, -10] %*% runif(9)

# a random response
Y <- rnorm(500)
```

Now we shuffle columns of `X` to see whether `NA` changes its position under `lm` estimation, or whether 0 changes its position under `gam` and `bam` estimation.

```
test <- function (fun = lm, seed = 0, ...) {
  shuffleFit <- function (fun) {
    shuffle <- sample.int(ncol(X))
    Xs <- X[, shuffle]
    b <- unname(coef(fun(Y ~ Xs, ...)))
    back <- order(shuffle)
    c(b[1], b[-1][back])
    }
  set.seed(seed)
  oo <- t(replicate(10, shuffleFit(fun)))
  colnames(oo) <- c("intercept", paste0("X", 1:ncol(X)))
  oo
  }
```

---

First we check with `lm`:

```
test(fun = lm)
```

We see that `NA` changes its position with column shuffling of `X`. Estimated coefficients vary, too.

---

Now we check with `gam`

```
library(mgcv)
test(fun = gam, method = "REML")
```

We see that estimation is invariant to column shuffling of `X`, and coefficient for `X5` is always 0.

---

Finally we check `bam` (`bam` is slow for small dataset like here. It is designed for large or super large dataset. So the following is noticeably slower).

```
test(fun = bam, gc.level = -1)
```

The result is as same as what we see for `gam`.

Answer (score 3):

**ec** , **examination** and **catholic** are 3 parameters in which you need ***at least 2 variable to determine the third***. 
The important part is that 2 out of 3 is always required. 
now when you pass this to lm , the first two of the 3 related variables will get coefficient and the third one will end up with NA . The order of variables are important. I hope this explains why both examination and catholic are not NA. with just ec alone , you cannot determine both examination as well as catholic