# R: Error in contrasts when fitting linear models with `lm`

Tags: r, regression, linear-regression, lm

I've found [Error in contrasts when defining a linear model in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18171246/error-in-contrasts-when-defining-a-linear-model-in-r) and have followed the suggestions there, but none of my factor variables take on only one value and I am still experiencing the same issue.

This is the dataset I'm using:  https://www.dropbox.com/s/em7xphbeaxykgla/train.csv?dl=0.

This is the code I'm trying to run:

```
simplelm <- lm(log_SalePrice ~ ., data = train)

#Error in `contrasts<-`(`*tmp*`, value = contr.funs[1 + isOF[nn]]) :
# contrasts can be applied only to factors with 2 or more levels
```

What is the issue?

Comment: What makes you think none of your factors only have one value? I don't want to download, import, and inspect your data set, but could you post the output of `sapply(train[!sapply(train, is.numeric)], function(x) length(unique(x)))`?

Comment: Glancing at your data, both the Utilities and the PoolQC columns look pretty 1-level (didn't scroll very much though...)

Comment: I posted the verifiably correct answer 12 minutes after question was asked, but 4 years later some anonymous idiot decided to mysteriously downvote it, so I deleted the solution. Here it is: https://pastebin.com/8M05yt6V

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for providing your dataset (I hope that link will forever be valid so that everyone can access). I read it into a data frame `train`.

Using the `debug_contr_error`, `debug_contr_error2` and `NA_preproc` helper functions provided by [How to debug "contrasts can be applied only to factors with 2 or more levels" error?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44200195/4891738), we can easily analyze the problem.

```
info <- debug_contr_error2(log_SalePrice ~ ., train)

## the data frame that is actually used by `lm`
dat <- info$mf

## number of cases in your dataset
nrow(train)
#[1] 1460

## number of complete cases used by `lm`
nrow(dat)
#[1] 1112

## number of levels for all factor variables in `dat`
info$nlevels
#     MSZoning        Street         Alley      LotShape   LandContour 
#            4             2             3             4             4 
#    Utilities     LotConfig     LandSlope  Neighborhood    Condition1 
#            1             5             3            25             9 
#   Condition2      BldgType    HouseStyle     RoofStyle      RoofMatl 
#            6             5             8             5             7 
#  Exterior1st   Exterior2nd    MasVnrType     ExterQual     ExterCond 
#           14            16             4             4             4 
#   Foundation      BsmtQual      BsmtCond  BsmtExposure  BsmtFinType1 
#            6             5             5             5             7 
# BsmtFinType2       Heating     HeatingQC    CentralAir    Electrical 
#            7             5             5             2             5 
#  KitchenQual    Functional   FireplaceQu    GarageType  GarageFinish 
#            4             6             6             6             3 
#   GarageQual    GarageCond    PavedDrive        PoolQC         Fence 
#            5             5             3             4             5 
#  MiscFeature      SaleType SaleCondition  MiscVal_bool      MoYrSold 
#            4             9             6             2            55
```

As you can see, `Utilities` is the offending variable here as it has only 1 level.

Since you have many character / factor variables in `train`, I wonder whether you have `NA` for them. If we add `NA` as a valid level, we could possibly get more complete cases.

```
new_train <- NA_preproc(train)

new_info <- debug_contr_error2(log_SalePrice ~ ., new_train)

new_dat <- new_info$mf

nrow(new_dat)
#[1] 1121

new_info$nlevels
#     MSZoning        Street         Alley      LotShape   LandContour 
#            5             2             3             4             4 
#    Utilities     LotConfig     LandSlope  Neighborhood    Condition1 
#            1             5             3            25             9 
#   Condition2      BldgType    HouseStyle     RoofStyle      RoofMatl 
#            6             5             8             5             7 
#  Exterior1st   Exterior2nd    MasVnrType     ExterQual     ExterCond 
#           14            16             4             4             4 
#   Foundation      BsmtQual      BsmtCond  BsmtExposure  BsmtFinType1 
#            6             5             5             5             7 
# BsmtFinType2       Heating     HeatingQC    CentralAir    Electrical 
#            7             5             5             2             6 
#  KitchenQual    Functional   FireplaceQu    GarageType  GarageFinish 
#            4             6             6             6             3 
#   GarageQual    GarageCond    PavedDrive        PoolQC         Fence 
#            5             5             3             4             5 
#  MiscFeature      SaleType SaleCondition  MiscVal_bool      MoYrSold 
#            4             9             6             2            55
```

We do get more complete cases, but `Utilities` still has one level. This means that most incomplete cases are actually caused by `NA` in your numerical variables, which we can do nothing (unless you have a statistically valid way to impute those missing values).

As you only have one single-level factor variable, the same method as given in [How to do a GLM when "contrasts can be applied only to factors with 2 or more levels"?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50297260/4891738) will work.

```
new_dat$Utilities <- 1

simplelm <- lm(log_SalePrice ~ 0 + ., data = new_dat)
```

The model now runs successfully. However, it is [rank-deficient](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37090722/4891738). You probably want to do something to address it, but leaving it as it is is fine.

```
b <- coef(simplelm)

length(b)
#[1] 301

sum(is.na(b))
#[1] 9

simplelm$rank
#[1] 292
```